# Remove n items from an array with object based on property name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array right here:

```
result = [{ID:"97",answerA:"Apple", answerB:"Chair",category:"MEAT"} , {ID:"97",answerA:"Apple", answerB:"Chair",category:"MEAT"}];
```

and so on.

> So far my array contains exactly 20 items out of 5 categories - so
>   that makes it 4 items for each category.

**I would like to resort my array so that it contains:**

- **4 items** for the category = *"Vegetables"*
- **3 items** for the category = *"Fingerfood"*
- **3 items** for the category = *"Seafood"*
- **3 items** for the category = *"Meat*"
- **2 items** for the category = *"General"*

  What would be the best way to resort my array to contain only 15 items based on the rules above.

**PS: Of course 5 items would be left out of the new, re-sorted array.**

*I have thought of looping through the array and using IF/Else statements to resort a new one but I would like to see the best and most simple way to do this.*

Comment: @FlorianGl err, is it possible to have a more comprehensive answer with some explanation?

Comment: if i wanted to give an answer, i would have written an answer :D

Comment: i just wanted to point out, that everyone has its own "best" way. for some its the one with less code, for others its the most readable code, aso.

Comment: As I thought about an answer, techfoobar's answer popped up. Imo this is a good solution, I would use that also. ;)

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanest imo will be using `Array.filter()` and counters for the exact categories you need.

```
// these are the categories and their allowed maxCounts
var counts = {
  "Vegetables": {maxCount: 4, count: 0},
  "Fingerfood": {maxCount: 3, count: 0},
  //...
};

// filtered is the reduced array containing just the ones you need
var filtered = result.filter(function(_item) {
  var c = counts[_item.category];

  // include only if allowed as per counts
  if(c && c.count < c.maxCount) { c.count++; return true; }

  return false;
});
```

PS:

1. Fill in the counts rule set as per your needs
2. Your category names in `counts` should match the case of the ones in `result`